# Java design for periodic update

Tags: model-view-controller

I am using websocket based MVC architecture, This MVC life cycle is similar to Spring and Struts, now I have to support periodic update for my views.

1. Each controller is responsible for each view present in the client
2. Controller has to update the view in a periodic interval
3. I am not maintain any session for each client. So the controller has to update for all clients.
4. I dont want to create thread inside Controller, because we have so many controllers for each view.
5. So, I want to create a separate module that has to handle this periodic update via Controller (by calling Controller methods).
6. At last, I want to keep the client just for display, so I dont want to keep timer in client side.

I want to follow some standard way to design this, please help me to follow the standard design patterns (like MVC) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Two cents of a spring, struts programmer for a websocket programmer.

**1.Each controller is responsible for each view present in the client**
[Good design, Hope you are not over engineering]

**Point 2 and point 3.**

Approach 1 - Since there is no session ask your UI/View to send a request to controller for update after a specific interval (say 2 mins) or after a specific event (say page refresh/reload) which ever suits your requirement.

Cons of the approach - Too many frequent updates by the UI/View side code can bring your application on its knees as client code can be changed and use to attack the application.

To avoid this you will need to take care in each request is authentic and complete in itself and can be executed independently.

Pros of the approach - Consider scaling an application, it can scale like anything.

**Point 4 and 5** they are similar

```
 controller {
    doSomething(){};
 }
```

Or

```
 controller {
 HelperCalssReference.doSomething(){};
 }
```

**you will always get a thread inside controller** [in terms of execution speed] but second approach is more decoupled.

**Point 6 and Point 3.**

"No timer on the client side" well then maintain session on the server side 
but "I am not maintain any session for each client" you have to keep it somewhere take a pick.

Don't maintain a session on server but have to keep track of the clients and send them new update say after 2 mins but how you will know when to stop or the client is offline if you want to stop say after 5 updates from the server you are good but your client UI may be online and waiting for updates.

**Point is have a logical break point in your program but can't find that in above requirements.**

**Probable Approaches -**

1. Use REST keeps an application scale-able and stateless.
   [https://capgemini.github.io/architecture/is-rest-best-microservices/ *must read section "Design / Implementation/ Configuration Difficulty"*]
2. Use Hollywood design principle but decide who is your Hollywood UI/view or the server.
3. Event driven approach can help let the user event decide when to ask for update 
   *[watch out for client asking for 3 updates in 1 second by multiple clicks.]*

Happy designing :)